# Doesn't vim 'fork' a shell to execute a command

Tags: c, linux, shell, vim, fork

I'm reading *APUE* about process groups. The book says,

> In most job-control shells, this function(*setpgid*) is called after a *fork* to have the child set its own process group ID. One of these calls is redundant, but by doing both, we are guaranteed that the child is placed into its own process group before either process assumes that this has happened.

I wrote the following piece of code in order to verify my understanding. Error handling is omitted.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{        
    printf("process ID: %d\n", getpid());
    printf("process group ID: %d\n", getpgrp());
    exit(0);
}
```

**output (run it directly into a shell):**

> process ID: 4388
>   process group ID: 4388

**output (run inside of vim):**

```
process ID: 4401  
process group ID: 4400    // pid of vim (through ps)
```

Why do the results differ? Doesn't vim fork a shell to execute a command? If it does, what is the difference or in other words, why the process group ID not equal to process ID like the first output?

BTW, does *fork* always automatically set the process group ID of child process? I tried to print the process group ID of a child process before set it and it printed the process ID of the parent process.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the shell gives you a new pgid when it starts your command; and vim doesn't.

Comment: How does vim execute a shell command? Doesn't it fork a shell to do that? What is the difference?

Comment: @Wisatbff: Just `fork` and `exec`, as oppsed to `fork`, `setpgid` and `exec`.

Comment: Does a process have to have a process group ID?

Comment: @Wisatbff: Yes. The pgid is inherited from the parent after a fork, until it's reset with `setpgid` (after which the pgid becomes equal to the pid).

Comment: @Wisatbff Vim does always run shell to run another program. That means there should be something like “if shell process is not a group leader then use pgid of the shell process” logic coded in shell source. In fact, if you run your program not directly from vim, but using `:!sh -c './your-program-name'` it will receive the same PGID inherited from Vim.